# wrap plain text inside a div before another html element

Tags: php, javascript

Ok, that probably doesn't make a ton of sense... let me illustrate:

`<div class="csl-entry">
lorem ipsum yada yada yada...
<a title="some title" rel="external" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>`

I would like to wrap the "lorem ipsum yada yada yada..." in a `<p>` tag, but am unsure how to proceed without also wrapping the `<a>`.

If it's easier to do in JavaScript or jQuery, I'm fine with that, too.  Much of my site is semi-dependent on a bit of JS anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery

```
$('.csl-entry').contents().filter(function() {

  return this.nodeType == 3;

}).wrap('<p></p>')
            })
```

Please note that this will wrap all text nodes that are children of csl-entry - so if you have any stray spaces in the div you will get an empty paragraph tag.

Comment: Is there a benefit of writing it this way over, say, something like this: $('.csl-entry').contents().filter(function() {

 if ( this.nodeType == 3 ) {
  $(this).wrap('<p />');
 }

});

Comment: Why use JS when he can just fix the source HTML?

Comment: I can't fix the source HTML. It's being pulled in via a 3rd party (Zotero).  Total mess.  Believe me, I would if I could...

Comment: @Jacob - I would say Michal's method is more correct because it keeps the semantic meaning of `filter()`, i.e., it actually uses it to filter and then uses `wrap()` on the results. Your way will work, but isn't really filtering as such given that nothing happens with the results of the filter, so you might just as well use `each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a `<a>` tag inside a `<p>` tag inside a `<div>` is perfectly ok.

So I'd say just do:

```
<div class="csl-entry"> 
     <p>
          lorem ipsum yada yada yada... 
          <a title="some title" rel="external" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
     </p>
</div>
```

If I understand your question well that is... :)

Comment: I don't have control over the source markup.  I have to hack it with either php or JS.  As I'm a bit more comfortable in JS, I'll probably go that route, though support would be better for PHP (for those with JS disabled)...

Comment: Much better to hack it with PHP - why depend on client-side vaguaries when you have the certainty of a server environment?